# How to determine in a shell script whether DHCP is running or not

Tags: linux, bash, dhcp, dhcp-server, embedded-linux

If I am running a shell script in linux environment, is there a way to determine whether DHCP is running or not?

Something like below is what I wish to do in pseudocode terms:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [DHCP is not Up?]
then
    wait for a second and recheck
fi

# Start my application
/usr/bin/MyHostApplication
```

I have a application which opens a TCP port. But I want to ensure that DHCP server is running before I start my application. I learnt from reading online that [DHCP](https://linuxconfig.org/what-is-dhcp-and-how-to-configure-dhcp-server-in-linux) is the one responsible for allowing clients to communicate to my host application using IP as `192.168.1.1`? So I am hoping that confirming DHCP server to be running should confirm that its all fine to open the port I want to?

Comment: Upon reading your question, I immediately thought of a clarifying follow-up question: are you talking about a DHCP process on the same computer, or a DHCP service on the local network?  But then I got to your last paragraph, and now I want to know: are you talking about verifying that a machine at a given IP address (192.168.1.1) is up? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I can remove the `192.168.1.1` related point in the question. I was thinking the DHCP server is up means that any client connected to my network would be able to connect to IP `192.168.1.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to check if the computer has already received its IP allocation
you could use this simple call:

```
ifconfig | grep 192.168.1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  wait for a second and recheck
fi
```

The only way the computer can get this IP address is if the DHCP server is up.

Comment: this is quite something that I was hoping for. Thanks. Trying this out

Comment: You might want to correct the typo `192.168.1` to `192.168.1.1` in your answer

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads It's not a typo if you were assigned a different address by DHCP, you could have any 192.168.1.xxx instead (unless you only care about 192.168.1.1 specifically, but it's often the default used by routers themselves), sometimes they're static & sometimes more random.

Comment: Interesting that `ifconfig | grep 192.168.1` does not give me any output but `ifconfig | grep 192.168` gives me a valid `inet addr:` and a Mask as well. Sorry, earlier I misunderstood and now I understand this better after testing it out. Thanks for your answer. Accepting it since it gives me the idea I was looking out for

Comment: It seems like your network mask is `255.255.0.0`, meaning bigger than a home network.